# Problems with creating line of sight in Unity 2D. Generated mesh position asynchronized with ray collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh

I'm working on a 2d top-down game for a college project and i, to a nosebleed, need player Darkwood-like line-of-sight. I steal some code from few youtube videos and trying to remade this code for my project, but meet this trouble. Main problem is in a visual mesh position, that follow player like that need, but doing it little faster than it should. So after few movements mesh found himself not in the center of character. Strange thing that ray collision is working correctly on character, independent of this mesh position, and show collision on this mesh like he`s in right place. All that i need now its synchronize this 2 things.
Code of the empty with code and mesh filter + renderer:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using CodeMonkey.Utils;

public class FOV : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask layerMask;
    private Mesh mesh;
    private float fov;
    private float viewDistance;
    private Vector3 origin;
    private float startingAngle;

    private void Start() {
        mesh = new Mesh();
        GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = mesh;
        fov = 90f;
        viewDistance = 50f;        
    }

    private void LateUpdate() {
        int rayCount = 50;
        float angle = startingAngle;
        float angleIncrease = fov / rayCount;
        GameObject EngObject = GameObject.FindWithTag("Eng");
        if (EngObject != null)
        {
            origin = Vector3.zero;
            origin = EngObject.transform.position;
        }

        Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[rayCount + 1 + 1];
        Vector2[] uv = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
        int[] triangles = new int[rayCount * 3];

        vertices[0] = origin;

        int vertexIndex = 1;
        int triangleIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= rayCount; i++) {
            Vector3 vertex;
            RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(origin, UtilsClass.GetVectorFromAngle(angle), viewDistance, layerMask);
            if (raycastHit2D.collider == null) {
                // No hit
                vertex = origin + UtilsClass.GetVectorFromAngle(angle) * viewDistance;
            } else {
                // Hit object
                vertex = raycastHit2D.point;
            }
            vertices[vertexIndex] = vertex;

            if (i > 0) {
                triangles[triangleIndex + 0] = 0;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 1] = vertexIndex - 1;
                triangles[triangleIndex + 2] = vertexIndex;

                triangleIndex += 3;
            }

            vertexIndex++;
            angle -= angleIncrease;
        }


        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.uv = uv;
        mesh.triangles = triangles;
        mesh.bounds = new Bounds(origin, Vector3.one * 1000f);
    }
```

Looking of Character Prefab and this empty(FOVV):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNBwV.png)

Problem Showcase:
[Spawn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCvAg.png)
[After few movings(angle in red circle must be in center of character)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WjepF.png)
[Collision working great, but like mesh in correct place in center of character(he dont)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rny8T.png)

I am a complete newbie to both Unity and C#. I try to change place of "FOVV" in hierarchy, try clear parameters in every update iteration and some kind of that, but all of this didnt help.